# R: Specifying dates between dateRangeInput - "Error in seq.int: 'to' must be a finite number"

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to define the dates between a user specified date range in Shiny R. I am using R version 3.6.2. However, I am obtaining an error:

> Error in seq.int: 'to' must be a finite number

when I am inputting the start and end dates values to a `seq` function. The `seq` works fine when I hardcode test start and end dates. The snippets of code are specified below, any advice to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

**UI Input Widget Code Parts**

```
dateRangeInput("date_range","Select Date Range",start = "NA",end = "NA",format="%Y-%m-%d")) ## For Date Range

div(DT::dataTableOutput("test_table"),style="width:50%;") ## For plotting table to check results
```

**Server**

```
observeEvent(input$date_range,{

  mins<- as.Date(input$date_range[1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
  maxs<- as.Date(input$date_range[2],format="%Y-%m-%d")

 dates <- seq(from=mins, to= maxs,by = 1)

 output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
   data.frame(dates),

   rownames = FALSE,
   options = list(searching = FALSE, pageLength = 5,lengthChange = FALSE)

 )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jay,

A few things might help:

- In the `ui`, I might use `as.Date(NA)` for your default `start` and `end` to ensure in `Date` format. And you can use default format for `dateRangeInput` which already is `yyyy-mm-dd`
- In `server`, check your `input$date_range` to make sure not `NA` that you start them out with. This will avoid giving `seq` an `NA` value to trigger your error.
- You can also make your `observeEvent` an `eventReactive` expression, and then take `output` out of it, which is preferable

Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("date_range","Select Date Range",start=as.Date(NA),end=as.Date(NA)), ## For Date Range
  div(DT::dataTableOutput("test_table"),style="width:50%;") ## For plotting table to check results
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dates <- eventReactive(input$date_range, {
    if (is.na(input$date_range[1]) | is.na(input$date_range[2])) return (NULL)

    mins<- as.Date(input$date_range[1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
    maxs<- as.Date(input$date_range[2],format="%Y-%m-%d")

    dates <- seq(from=mins, to=maxs, by = 1)
  })

  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    data.frame(dates()),
    rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(searching = FALSE, pageLength = 5,lengthChange = FALSE)
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Dear Ben, Thank you very much for taking the time to respond and help me out. It did indeed work and based on your guide, I have now understood that it was due to 'NA' being input to the 'seq' and to better use the eventReactive to return the value. Thanks again. Very much appreciated.